# Delphi: VK_SPACE, the right key

Tags: delphi

I am a little perplexed. On :
http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/blvkc.htm

it says that the right key for "Space" is #20. Tried that and it will not work.
However, replacing it with #32 seems to work :

```
procedure TForm14.cxTextEdit5KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not (Key in [#8,#32, '0'..'9']) then begin
  ShowMessage('Only numbers !');
  Key := #0;
  end;
end;
```

So now I am unsure if this will work on all Windows versions ?

Comment: `VK_SPACE` is an integer constant, `Key` is a variable of type `Char`.

Comment: @TOndrej You could use `Chr(VK_SPACE)` to convert `VK_SPACE` into character and then perform character to character comparison.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, or you could compare with `Ord(Key)`.

Comment: @TOndrej That is correct.

Comment: I think all of those are semantically wrong because virtual key codes are different from character codes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed and edited my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. [`VK_SPACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) is defined as `0x20` (in C notation hexadecimal value `20` which is equal to `32`) in all versions of Windows.
Your link lists hexadecimal values, too.

**Edit**

As David points out, the virtual key code `VK_SPACE` is irrelevant in the context of an `OnKeyPress` event handler. (The fact that it's defined with the ASCII value of the space character should be treated as coincidental.)

You can simply rely on the fact that `#32` is the correct notation for the space character (also `#$20` or simply `' '`).

Answer (score 4):

> It says that the right key for "Space" is #20.

No it does not. `#20` is the character with ordinal of 20 decimal. The table you refer to contains hexadecimal values. `VK_SPACE` is a virtual key code, an integer, whose value is 32 in decimal, 20 in hexadecimal.

However, virtual key codes are not used by the `OnKeyPress` event handler and the value of `VK_SPACE` is simply not relevant to your question. The `OnKeyPress` event handler uses UTF-16 character codes. The UTF-16 character code for a space is 32 decimal, 20 hexadecimal. If you use a pre-Unicode Delphi, `OnKeyPress` uses ANSI instead of UTF-16.

It is worth remembering that `OnKeyPress` uses UTF-16/ANSI codes because it corresponds to `WM_CHAR`. And `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` use virtual key codes by way of being triggered from `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`.